# how to pass list of Account

Tags: webservices

```
    public class SourceMDMRestAPI{
        public static string GenerateKey(REST_AccountService_V1.AccountWrapper  acctList){
    //for this acctList ,i want to create list of records.
    for(Account i:acctList){
Account A=new Account(Name=i.Name);
new list<Account> tococati();
tococati.add(i);//i want to do this ,but it is throwing error loop must iterate over a collectionREST_AccountService_V1.AccountWrapper 
    }


    @RestResource(urlMapping='/v1/accounts/*')

    global with sharing class REST_AccountService_V1 {
    global class AccountWrapper {
            public List<Account> acctList;
            public String status;
            public String message;
            public string sname;
            public AccountWrapper(){
                acctList = new List<Account>();
            }
    }
```

I have to collect list elements and I have to create records for the list.I started like above please  help how to achieve it.

Comment: Can you put your code in code block so that it will be helpful to read/understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to something like. As your collection type is `REST_AccountService_V1.AccountWrapper` you need to iterate it using this.

```
public static string GenerateKey(REST_AccountService_V1.AccountWrapper  acctList){
     List<account> accList = new List<Account>();
    //for this acctList ,i want to create list of records.
    for(REST_AccountService_V1.AccountWrapper i:acctList){
          Account A=new Account(Name=i.sname);
          accList .add(A);
    }
    insert accList;
}
```

Comment: @sasfdc What is not working. Can you please explain.

Comment: The names `acctList` and `accList` are so similar it would be easy to get them mixed up.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are messing up the List of Wrapper with List of Account.

Couple of observations

1. In the for loop you are trying to iterate the wrapper, but using Account on RHS, probably want to use the wrapper instead.
2. You are declaring the account list inside the for loop and inserting from inside the loop, which doesnt sound like a good idea. You probably want to do the dml outside the loop.